# How to do a for loop with React and why is my Component not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Pokecard from "./Pokecard";
import "./Pokedex.css";

class Pokedex extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    pokemon: [],
    getData() {
      for (let i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            this.pokemon.push({
              id: data.id,
              namePoke: data.name,
              type: data.types[0].type.name,
              base_experience: data.base_experience,
            });
          });
      }
    },
  };
  render() {
    this.props.getData();
    return (
      <div className="Pokedex">
        <div className="Pokedex-grid">
          {this.props.pokemon.map((p) => (
            <Pokecard
              id={p.id}
              name={p.namePoke}
              type={p.type}
              exp={p.base_experience}
              key={p.id}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pokedex;
```

I am new to React and I don't understand why my for loop runs multiple times so I get the Pokecards twice or more.
Also, the whole Component Pokedex is not showing up when reloading the page. What do I do wrong?

Comment: `render` gets called whenever `setState` get called meaning you have an infinite loop. look into using lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0):

@azium made a great comment. You are calling to get data in your render, which is setting state, and causing a re-render, which is calling getData again, which is fetching data again and then setting state again, and the cycle continues on and on indefinitely. Also, default props should only define properties default values, but in this case you don't need a getData default prop. All you need to do is call the getData method in your componentDidMount. And your method needs to store the data in state, and not do a direct property change (like you are doing). Here is an example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Pokecard from "./Pokecard";
import "./Pokedex.css";

class Pokedex extends Component {
  static state = {
    pokemon: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }
  getData() {
      for (let i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
        const pokemon = [...this.state.pokemon];
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i}`)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            pokemon.push({
              id: data.id,
              namePoke: data.name,
              type: data.types[0].type.name,
              base_experience: data.base_experience,
            });
        });
        this.setState({pokemon});
      }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Pokedex">
        <div className="Pokedex-grid">
          {this.state.pokemon.map((p) => (
            <Pokecard
              id={p.id}
              name={p.namePoke}
              type={p.type}
              exp={p.base_experience}
              key={p.id}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pokedex;
```